# How to have a batch file randomly select one of 3 vbs files

Tags: batch-file, vbscript

Okay, so I have a little side-project that I've been working on. I have 3 vbs files that play short audio files. I want to have an already existing program randomly execute one of these vbs files. As the music is all electronic drops, the vbs files are named:

1-2-bass.vbs

bass.vbs

wolf-drop.vbs

These files are all in the same folder, I just need a batch file to randomly select one of them and execute it...... and I don't know how to do that......

Answer (score 1):

```
echo off
set "c=1-2-bass bass wolf-drop"
set /a r=%random% %% 3 +1
for /f "tokens=%r%" %%i in ("%c%") do echo %%i.vbs
```

remove the `echo` or replace it with `start`

Answer (score 0):

It's easier to do this in VBScript:

```
scripts = Array("C:\path\to\1-2-bass.vbs", _
            "C:\path\to\bass.vbs", _
            "C:\path\to\wolf-drop.vbs"
          )

Randomize
Set sh = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

sh.Run scripts(Int(Rnd * 3)), 0, True
```